# Um campo dinâmico para cada registro do banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu tenho uma propriedade chamada ProductDevelopment onde eu tenho várias funções e devo atribuir um usuário para cada função. Eu tenho um EditorTemplate para retornar uma lista de usuários. Eu tenho que criar um campo de forma dinâmica para cada função registrada no banco de dados e cada campo irá utilizar o EditorTemplate para listar usuários. (como na imagem abaixo). Eu criei um EditorTemplate (FuncoesUsuarios.cshtml) fortemente tipado (`@model ICollection<FuncaoUsuario>`), que gera os campos, como na imagem abaixo, mas eu não sei o que fazer para que os valores sejam devolvidos ao Modelo. Pensei em usar um multiselect oculto, mas estou achando muito complicado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha classe

```
public class FuncaoUsuario //Não mapeado
{
    public int IdFuncao { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string DscFuncao { get; set; }
}
```

Meu campo na View (propriedade ProductDevelopment)

```
public ICollection<FuncaoUsuario> ProductDevelopment { get; set; }
```

Meu EditorTemplate -> FuncoesUsuarios.cshtml

```
@model ICollection<FuncaoUsuario>
@{
    var modelMetaData = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata;
    var propertyName = modelMetaData.PropertyName;    
}




@foreach (FuncaoUsuario item in this.Model)
{
    var id = "id" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);    
    List<SelectListItem> listValues = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Usuario))
    {
        listValues.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = item.Usuario, Value = item.Usuario });
    }     
    <div id="@id" class="field-middle">
        <h3>@String.Format(Html.LabelFor(model => model).ToString(), item.DscFuncao) :</h3>
        @Html.DropDownList("", listValues, new { id = "PD" + item.IdFuncao.ToString() })
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $("#@id select")
            .turnAutoComplete("@Url.Action("UsersListJson", "Security")");
    </script> 
}


<select name="@propertyName" multiple="multiple" size=30 style='height: 100%;' >
@foreach (FuncaoUsuario item in this.Model)
{   
<option value="@item.IdFuncao">teste</option>
}
</select>
```

[EDITADO]

Fiz as alterações conforme abaixo usando BeginCollectionItem

Models:

```
public partial class Modelo
{
    public ICollection<FuncaoUsuario> ProductDevelopment { get; set; }
    //Continua...
}
public class FuncaoUsuario 
{
    public int IdFuncao { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string DscFuncao { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResultBase Editar(int id)
{
    Modelo model = this.Service.GetForEdit(this.IdEmpresa, id);
    return base.SwitchView(model);
}
```

View Principal:

```
 @model Modelo

    <div class="box-fields">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            this.DefaultActionEdit,
            "Modelo",
            new DefaultAjaxOptions()
        ))
        {      
@Html.EditorFor(i => i.ProductDevelopment) //precisa desta propriedade na view principal, pra nao dar o erro mencionado abaixo. E tem que remover o template Collection.cshtml.
            foreach (FuncaoUsuario userFunction in this.Model.ProductDevelopment)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_UsuarioFuncao", userFunction);
            }   

    //Mais coisas....
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@model FuncaoUsuario

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ProductDevelopment")) 
{  

    List<SelectListItem> listValues = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Model.Usuario))
    {
        listValues.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = this.Model.Usuario, Value = this.Model.Usuario });
    }

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdFuncao)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Usuario, "Usuario")    
}
```

Erro encontrado:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Source Error: 


Line 1:  @model FuncaoUsuario
Line 2:  
Line 3:  @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ProductDevelopment")) <- erro nesta linha.
Line 4:  {
```

Comment: procure por BeginCollectionItem, é um helper asp.net mvc para esse tipo de situação

Comment: Devolvidos para o *Model* ou para o *Controller*?

Comment: Devolvidos para o Model (Editor Template tipado). BeginCollectionItem parece ser o que estou procurando. Qual namespace devo utilizar, por que eu tentei fazer assim  `using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("FuncaoUsuario"))`, porém o helper não reconheceu "BeginCollectionItem"?

Comment: Eu coloquei a imagem de como deverá ficar a view (tinha esquecido).

Comment: Acabo de achar o Nuget ->  Install-Package BeginCollectionItem (vou tentar usar e ver como fica.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É um caso clássico do uso do [pacote NuGet `BeginCollectionItem`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). Ele não é nativo do ASP.NET MVC ou do Razor. Precisa ser instalado.

[Já respondi várias perguntas a respeito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem). Se necessário, favor editar sua pergunta para que eu possa fazer os devidos complementos na resposta.

---

**EDIT**

Havendo este erro:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

É porque o BeginCollectionItem insere um `EditorTemplate` chamado `Collection.cshtml` que pode dar alguns problemas. É recomendável apagá-lo para definir sua *Partial*.

A localização exata desse *Template* fica em `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Collection.cshtml`.

Comment: Eu editei minha pergunta e coloquei o codigo alterado para usar oBeginCollectionItem. Do jeito que esta ai esta dando erro (ver no final da pergunta editada).

Comment: @Elizeu Qual a necessidade disso? `var id = "id" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);`. O `BeginCollectionItem` já define um Id provisório pra você. Você pode definir outro identificador no *Controller* na hora de salvar.

Comment: Este "id" é lixo, esqueci de deletar quando copiei de outro template. Mas não é o motivo do erro eu já tirei ele.

Comment: ele nao ta reconhecendo "ProductDevelopment" como uma collection.

Comment: @Elizeu Ou algum `userFunction` está nulo. Faça um *Debug*.

Comment: Fiz o Debug e todos itens tem valor. O `"BeginCollectionItem("ProductDevelopment")"` está correto? Eu coloco entre aspas a propriedade do meu model?

Comment: @Elizeu Sim, essa parte está correta. Pelo que eu me lembre, esse erro do `index` é algo muito bobo, e que tem a ver com a coleção em si. `index` é um campo que o componente coloca no *form* pra identificar os itens de uma coleção.

Comment: Eu reinstalei o pacote BeginCollecionItem e parou de dar erro. Agora ta entrando em um template "Collection.cshtml" que vem com o pacote. Eu tenho que usar esta view (Collection.cshtml) para montar meus campos?

Comment: @Elizeu Ah! É isso mesmo. Remova este template que o problema deve parar.

Comment: Agora funcinou. Só tem um defeito. Eu preciso que o id fique em um HiddenFor e ele ta exibindo os valores. Mas o principal já deu certo.

Comment: @Elizeu Isso é mais simples. Precisa de ajuda?

Comment: Não, o pior já passou. Estou nisto desde ontem. O arquiteto saiu de férias e eu não tinha a quem recorrer.

Comment: Já descobri. O problema não era o HiddenFor, era isto -> `@Html.EditorFor(i => i.ProductDevelopment)`, tava exibindo os ids. Troquei pra isto @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.ProductDevelopment) e resolveu. Valeu pela ajuda.